# Why and how returning the address of a static variable is OK while doing the same with non-static variable gives wrong result?

Tags: c, static

```
char str[] = "hello";
```

This definition dosn't work but

```
static char str[] = "hello"
```

This works, why?

Full code:

```
char *retstr(void)
    {
        char str[] = "hello"; //This definition dosnt work
        return str;
    }

    int main()
    {
        printf("\n%s\n",retstr());
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In case of

```
 char str[] = "hello"; //This definition dosnt work
```

you're trying to return the address of a local variable `str`. Using the returned value is  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) here, because once the `retstr()` function finishes execution, there is no existence of the `str` variable.

OTOH,

```
 static char str[] = "hello";
```

works, because, the `static` variable as *static storage duration*. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program. So even after the `retstr()` function finishes execution, `str` remains valid, and hence, the return value is valid to be used.

Related: `C11`, chapter §6.2.4, *Storage durations of objects*, Paragraph 3

> ... with the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, has *static storage duration*. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[] = "hello"; //This definition dosnt work
return str;
```

Here you are returning the local address. that's why it is not working

```
static char str[] = "hello"
```

while in this one, you are changing the scope of the 'str' variable to the whole program. that's why it works.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return local variables from a function. Local variables live on the stack, and once the function completes, that stack space is released and can be used by the next function call.

```
char str[] = "hello"; //this won't work as it is a local variable
```

Once you come out of the scope there doesn't exist any variable named `str` for other function calls.

But `static` variable lifetime extends across the entire run of the program.

```
static char str[] = "hello"; //this will work
```

Hence on using `static` it is not giving any error.

Answer (score 0):

Static variables are created once and does not get destroyed when a function returns but local variables gets destroyed once our function ends.

local variable are created every time a function is called and gets destroyed when it returns.

> In case of local variable : you are returning a pointer to a string which exists no-more. 
>   
>   In case of global variable : the string is still there and hence it will always work.